# What is this Australian weed with red flowers and green leaves?

Tags: identification, weed-control

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: pretty sure its not the mexican cigar plant cause the flower is all red not a purple white tip, and its NOT australian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is [*Stephanophysum longifolium*](http://www.saveourwaterwaysnow.com.au/01_cms/details_pop.asp?ID=1297).

> Naturalised in Bellingen (North Coast) and in Queensland. Also
>   naturalised throughout many of the Pacific islands.

[image: Flowers and leaves of Ruellia brevifolia (synonym R. graecizans)]
Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ruellia_graecizans.JPG

Author: [Oeropium](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Oeropium&action=edit&redlink=1)